# How to set up water planting system?

Tags: houseplants, watering

I am an engineer and I want to put a garden inside my house. What I mean is indoor garden. However, I don't want any insects. I googled about this topic and found that water planting may be an option. How I could NOT use soil to grow plant?

Comment: look at this link for hydroponics http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=hydroponics

Answer (score 4):

It's called hydroponics. There are many sites that will help with installation plans/instructions [(example 1,](http://www.homehydrosystems.com/) [2,](http://www.hydroponics.eu/hydroponics-grow-room-setup_28-146.html) [3,](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Setup-and-Run-a-Hydroponics-System/) [4)](http://www.wikihow.com/Build-a-Homemade-Hydroponics-System). There are may kinds of hydroponic setups, and you can choose the one that seems most suitable to your needs.

You'll need a reservoir for the water, submersible nutrient pump, timers (for lighting and possibly pump), nutrient delivery system, plant tray or pipe, water source, air pump, mounting hardware, piping, electricity source, and of course a lighting system.

If your only turn-off from indoor gardening with soil is the insects, you still have options there. For instance, you can sterilize your garden soil in an oven, or buy a sterile bagged soil/mix.